# Maximum number of arguments in MSVC 2012 RC std::thread implementation?

Tags: c++, multithreading, visual-c++, c++11, visual-studio-2012

Apparently there's a maximum number of arguments for std::thread for the std::thread implementation in the current MSVC 2012 RC.

This code compiles fine with both MSVC and g++ with -std=c++0x:

```
std::thread t = std::thread(printf, "%d, %d, %d, %d", 1, 2, 3, 4);
t.join();
```

But for more than 6 arguments, MSVC returns an error:

```
std::thread t = std::thread(printf, "%d, %d, %d, %d, %d", 1, 2, 3, 4, 5);
t.join();
```

> error C2661: 'std::thread::thread' : no overloaded function takes 7
>   arguments

Is this somehow intended? Or maybe a bug in the MSVC implementation? Is it because there's no support for variadic templates in MSVC yet?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

MSVC2010 does not have variadic templates so they're implemented with the help of the preprocessor.

I think you can set a `#define` to set the number of arguments supported. I can check later, when i'm back at home, which one it is.

**EDIT**:

I just realized this is about 2012 version. As can bee read in [VS connect bug report](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/747001/c-variadic-templates-fail-to-compile-vs2012) it still does not support variadic templates.

Comment: Thanks! The preprocessor argument is _VARIADIC_MAX according to http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2011/09/12/10209291.aspx. There's still a maximum number of 10 arguments, though.